# why this python code working reverse order

Tags: python, design-patterns, jupyter-notebook, singleton, random-seed

It seems like the following python code which is a demo implementation of singleton design pattern working reverse order. can anyone explain why?

```
import random

class Rng:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Rng, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.number = random.randint(a, b)

b = Rng(4, 33)
a = Rng(100, 200)
print(a.number , b.number)
```

```
output: 148 148
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRdz3.png)

since b is initiating first it should be always between 4 to 33, for **a** as well. But it's initiating **a** first

Comment: It's the same object, but you run `__init__` twice. The second call overwrites the data from the first.

Comment: In `__new__`, you should add `cls._instance.number = random.randint(*args, **kwargs)`, since you only want that to happen *once*, when the singelton is first created. There's no need to define `__init__` at all.